# Check if selected item equals, otherwise dont do that

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

Good day,

So I have 3 loops that doesnt matter anyway. But I want to put them into an if method. I use winforms and I only want the application to execute the loops IF the selected Item of my combobox/dropdownlist is "arabisch". Could you help me fixing my code? visual studio green marked the line with the if statement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Friedhof_Generator
{
    public partial class frm_Grabnummer : Form
    {
        public frm_Grabnummer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Feld.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");

            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Reihe.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");

            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Arabisch");
            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Römisch");
            ddl_Nr.Items.Add("Alphabetisch");
        }

        private void ddl_Feld_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int FeldVon, FeldBis, ReiheVon, ReiheBis, NrVon, NrBis;
            string Friedhof;

            FeldVon = int.Parse(tb_Von_Feld.Text);
            FeldBis = int.Parse(tb_Bis_Feld.Text);
            ReiheVon = int.Parse(tb_Von_Reihe.Text);
            ReiheBis = int.Parse(tb_Bis_Reihe.Text);
            NrVon = int.Parse(tb_Von_Nr.Text);
            NrBis = int.Parse(tb_Bis_Nr.Text);
            Friedhof = tb_Friedhof.Text;

            if (ddl_Feld.SelectedItem == "Arabisch")
            {


                while (NrVon < NrBis)
                {
                    lb_Ausgabe.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", Friedhof, FeldVon, ReiheVon, NrVon));
                    NrVon++;

                    if (NrVon == NrBis)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                while (ReiheVon < ReiheBis)
                {
                    lb_Ausgabe.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", Friedhof, FeldVon, ReiheVon, NrVon));
                    ReiheVon++;

                    if (ReiheVon == ReiheBis)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                while (FeldVon < FeldBis)
                {
                    lb_Ausgabe.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", Friedhof, FeldVon, ReiheVon, NrVon));
                    FeldVon++;

                    if (FeldVon == FeldBis)
                    {
                        lb_Ausgabe.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", Friedhof, FeldVon, ReiheVon, NrVon));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ddl_Feld.SelectedItem == "Arabisch"
```

With this line you are checking, if the referenct to `ddl_Feld.SelectedItem` is the same as to "Arabisch". Which it's not.

You should change the comparison to

```
ddl_Feld.SelectedItem.Equals("Arabisch", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Strings should not be compared with `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Since, `Combobox.SelectedItem` returns a object and not the string therefore it marked the green line on the `if`. There could be a few possibilities which you can try instead of

```
ddl_Feld.SelectedItem == "Arabisch"
```

you can use

```
ddl_Feld.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Arabisch"
```

or

```
ddl_Feld.GetItemText(ddl_Feld.SelectedItem) == "Arabisch"
```

or

```
ddl_Feld.Text == "Arabisch"
```

Comment: Or you could also use ddl_Feld.SelectedItem.Equals("Arabisch")